# Angular stack error in release, reverse engineer AOT to find bug location

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a bug reporting from a global handler in Angular.
I receieve an error from the field with the stack of:

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys () at new D (https://galy.siga.me/signstudio/main.db5360e4525ea25e.js:1:2693502) at Ms.D.ɵfac [as factory] (https://galy.siga.me/signstudio/main.db5360e4525ea25e.js:1:2695538
```

and the stack at that line:

```
}unsubStationListener(){this.m_stationSub$&&this.m_stationSub$.unsubscribe()}updateStations(y){this.dataSource?this.dataSource.data=y:this.dataSource=new e.by(y)}updateGeoLocation(){if(0===this.dataSource.data.length)return this.markerPositions=[];this.dataSource.data.forEach((y,A)=>{var C,T;const U=this.findGeoMarker(y.props.station_business_id);if((null===(C=null==y?void 0:y.geo)||void 0===C?void 0:C.lat)&&(null===(T=null==y?void 0:y.geo)||void 0===T?void 0:T.lon)){const f=Number(y.geo.lat)+.01*A,W=Number(y.geo.lon);this.updateMarker(y.stat.$.station_business_id,f,W,y.stat.$.socket,y.stat.$.name,U)}else this.removeMarker(U)})}findGeoMarker(y){return this.markerPositions.findIndex(A=>A.station_business_id===y)}destroy(){super.destroy(),this.unsubStationListener()}}return D.\u0275fac=function(y){return new(y||D)(w.Y36(M.C3),w.Y36(g.uw),w.Y36(B.Vn),w.Y36(L.eN))},D.\u0275cmp=w.Xpm({type:D,selectors:[["app-station-map"]],inputs:{filterByStation:"filterByStation",setZoom:"setZoom"},features:[w.qOj],decls:5,vars:2,consts:[[1,"debug"],[4,"ngIf"],["height","700px","width","100%",3,"center","zoom","mapClick","mapMousemove","mapRightclick"],[3,"position","options","mapClick",4,"ngFor","ngForOf"],[3,"position","options","mapClick"],["marker",""]],template:function(y,A){1&y&&(w.TgZ(0,"small",0),w._uU(1),w.qZA(),w._uU(2,"\n"),w.YNc(3,
```

How can I decipher this? I looked and looked and can't figure where its coming from.

any tricks to track down a stack error from AOT release?

regadrs

Sean.

Comment: Is this a runtime or a build error? If runtime only, can you reproduce this locally using ng serve —prod?

Comment: that's the problem, its runtime and I dont know how to reproduce unless I understand where it fails.